# Ubuntu 18.04 : Orange dotted line appearing at the bottom of the screen

Tags: 18.04, graphics, display, screen

am a beginner Linux user and love Ubuntu for its simplicity and stability. But suddenly out of nowhere "there appears a line at the bottom of my screen it's orange in colour and in dotted form", it is pretty annoying having to look at that. So please help me to give some advice's of fixing it..

FYI I've updated Ubuntu and also have all the necessary drivers installed correctly.. everything was perfect and this problem just suddenly appeared.

I've clicked a pic since the line wasn't appearing on screenshots.

[image: Image is Attached]

Comment: The line is not appearing in screenshot .. it is on the bottom of the screen on every window..

Comment: can you change the location of your dock to left or right and see, still the line is visible?

Comment: i did that already .. didn't solve the problem

Comment: seems like hardware issue.

Comment: i don't think so.. it just happen suddenly.. everything was fine before.. and also i didn't installed any new hardware.. am in dual booted machine and the line is not appearing in windows 10 .. it's just in Ubuntu

Comment: can you chk now in windows 10. what is the shell theme you are using in Ubuntu?

Comment: yes checked in windows 10 its fine there. and am using default shell theme.. if its any concern i've already tried changing the theme to default.. the problem still remains.. :(

Comment: Ok can you change the wallpaper and see once. i withdraw my comment reg. hardware

Comment: yes already tried changing the wallpaper..

Comment: do you have any other DE installed?

Comment: no everything is on default..

Comment: can you change to `Ubuntu on Wayland` now by logging out and selecting wayland..

Comment: okay thanks mate switched to wayland nd back and surprisingly its gone.. :)

Answer (score 0):

as a workaround try to log in with different desktop sessions other than the present one and see.

for example:
while at login screen, click the gear icon and choose "Ubuntu on Wayland"
[image]

and then again login with default session.